# How to see the value of an object property in Xcode at a breakpoint

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I have a parent node contain all object :

```
SKNode* _moving;
_moving = [SKNode node];
[self addChild:_moving];
...
[_moving addChild:spritenodetexture];
```

now I want to check the speed value of "_moving" which is "_moving.speed";
So I set a break point at that line of condition:

```
if (_moving.speed > 0) {
```

How do I know the value of  "_moving.speed" at that point ? Look into debug windows, I only see the address, postion, etc., but no value! Does Xcode Debug has tool to see it but I don't know ?
(I am using SpriteKit in Xcode)

Comment: Simply click in speed in text editor while debugging, should dispaly a pop up.

Comment: I single click, double click, nothing of the value showed.

Comment: withou click just place the mouse pointer over the variable

Comment: The Xcode debug data display is highly buggy.  Use the console.  Assuming `speed` is a scalar and not an object, type `p [_moving speed]` in the console.  (Sometimes it will let you type `p _moving.speed`, other times that confuses it.)  If you want to print an object use `po` instead of `p`.

Comment: Note that in no view can you access `_moving` before it's been assigned.

Comment: place mouse there is not working for me. The typing "p" is working without the square bracket. It shows (CGFloat) $2 = 1. If I use print,  the result is : (CGFloat) $0 = 1. Same value, but I dont know why $0 and $2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern versions of Xcode use [LLDB](http://lldb.llvm.org/).

The easiest way to inspect scoped variables during a breakpoint is to use the "Variables View" from within the Debug Area: **View > Debug Area > Show Debug Area** and then click the "Show Variables View" button (i.e., second-to-last icon in the lower right-hand corner). You can then explore the tree of variables in scope.

[image]

Optionally (though I've personally had varied success) you can simply hover your mouse cursor over the variable in question and Xcode should pop up a tool tip with some options.

You can also issue **LLDB** commands from the console itself. To print out your variable, execute the following command:

```
print [_moving speed]
```

[Here's a handy list of **LLDB** commands and their older **GDB** counterparts](http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html).

Comment: Sorry I follow your instruction but I couldn't figure out what icon you are mentioning. And the print command, looks like it cannot be recognised: "Use of undeclared identifier "print" "

Comment: @user1314404 I've updated my answer with a sample image that shows the **Variables View** (i.e., the left-hand, white pane), the icon to toggle said panel and an example of a `print` command.

Comment: Now I got what you mean! Yes, can type command there, but in my case it works without the square bracket! One more thing, typing "p" it shows result: (CGFloat) $2 = 1. If I use "print", the result is : (CGFloat) $0 = 1. Same value, but I dont know why $0 and $2 ?

Comment: `p` is just a short-hand alias for `print`. `$0..$9` are persistent variables that simply store the results of your commands for convenience.